# When my string contain null character in c program?

Tags: c, string, printf, null-terminated

I still don't know, when my string in c program contain null-terminated and when it doesn't contain.

Sample of my code

```
...
float t0 = 2.43, t1 = 3.42, t2 = 1, t3 = 10.9;
...
printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f", t0, t1, t2, t3); 
...
```

If i use printf like in my code, does c program will automatically add null-terminated at the end of string that printed or no?

Comment: Maybe some [documentation for `printf()` will help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). The `printf` function sends the resulting output to `stdout`. No terminator is emitted. Or were you thinking of `sprintf()` ?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see any _string_ here...

Comment: @SouravGhosh The OP appears to be referring to the output content of `printf`, and whether *it* finishes with a null-terminator (which it doesn't). So far, no answer below seem to have picked up on that. My cheap-glass, out-of-round, poor excuse for a crystal ball tells me the question is eventually related to stdout redirection and whether that output adds a terminator to the target device.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes sir, now i got the point. Till time, answers are confusing, though.

Comment: i am confuse, which is true? people give different answer below

Comment: @Anti Mafia  Confusion comes form wondering if you are talking about the format string or the output of `printf()`.  See edit in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28965233/2410359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: If i use printf like in my code, does c program will automatically add null-terminated at the end of string that printed or no?
A: No.  `printf()` does not typical print the terminating null character `'\0'`.  Instead `"%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f"` causes output like "1.12 2.23 3.34 4.45" with the last character printed as `'5'`.

[Edit]
The format `"%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f"` is a string which ends with a null terminator `'\0'`.  The printed output of `printf()` did not print a `'\0'`.  The null terminator `'\0'` in the format signals to `printf()` to stop.  The null terminator `'\0'` itself is not printed.

Note:  In C, a *C string* always has a terminating null character `'\0'`.  If an array of `char` does not contain one, it is not a string.  So the output of `printf()` in the above example is not a string, but simply a series of characters.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st argument to

```
printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f", ...
```

is a string literal (`"%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f"`) and yes, also string literals are `0`-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to `If i use printf like in my code, does the string that printed contain null character at the end?` is yes it contains but you will not see it in printf.

The null terminator indicates the end of a string when represented as an array of characters. When using the printf function you pass a pointer to the beginning of the string as a parameter and it will print the string until the NULL terminator.

Comment: `NULL` != `null`; `null`== `NUL` == `0`

Answer (score 0):

Effectively yes, had you declared `char format[]="%f %f\n";`
Using gdb or adding some research code you'd be able to see the nul byte terminating the string.